# How to selenium test web sites depending on each other? (OAuth2 IdS, protected sites)

Tags: selenium, teamcity

I have an IdS (Thinktecture Identity Server3) and various web sites trusting the IdS.

I have selenium tests for IdS and for each of the sites.

I use TeamCity and Octopus Deploy.

Changes in IdS should trigger test of dependent web sites. Changes in individual sites should trigger only test of the site (as it is).

What is the best way of ensuring this? I should think this is a common problem? ;)

BR, Anders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for in the most obvious of places. On the web site builds, I added a Finish Build Trigger pointing to the ids build. This way all my sites (I have only one :)) gets selenium tested.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do so, is to use App settings configuration options of the .Net itself. You can use config transformations to create different configuration per site and change. You will have to however map each, though. This will allow you to keep everything in the project. Example of such script creating transformed config files using the command line transform execution [tool](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebConfigTransformRunner/). Or if you prefer to use TeamCity with XML [pokes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/xmlpoke-task). I've used the later with great success on Selenium and multi site platform test framework. Before each test build that was chained, we modified the XMLs, so the execution was dedicated to the related Git branch or repo that TeamCity was set to monitor.